# How many integers $k$ in $[-500,500]$ are such that $\log(kx)=2\log(x+2)$ has exactly one real solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> How many integers $k$ are in the range $[-500,500]$ such that the equation $\log(kx)=2\log(x+2)$ has exactly one real solution?

I deduced that $kx$ and $(x+2)$ must be greater than $0$ and that $(x+2)^2=kx$ and used quadratic formula but don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: What was the result of the quadratic formula? Note that the very short intro to MathJax at https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation happens to use the quadratic formula as an example, in case you need help writing it.

Answer (score 0):

We use an algebraic approach. Since $\log(kx)=2\log(x+2)$, then $kx = (x+2)^2$, meaning $x^2+(4-k)x+4=0$. Our original equation has exactly one solution if and only if there is only one solution to the above equation, or one of the solutions is extraneous; it involves the computation of the log of a nonpositive number.

For the first case, the only valid solution is $k=8, x=2.$ For the second case, we can use the quadratic formula. We have $x = \frac{k-4 \pm \sqrt{k^2-8k}}2,$ so in order for there to be at least one real solution, the discriminant must be nonnegative, or $k < 0$ or $k > 8$. Note that if $k > 8$, then both solutions will be positive, and therefore both valid. Therefore, $k < 0$.

Thus, the numbers that work are from $[-500, -1] U [8]$, which is $501$ solutions.

Comment: Why will all $k<0$ work?Furthermore I think this is a copied solution.